# How do I make my local git reflect master in Github?

Tags: git, github

I don't think I'm even asking this right. Here is my situation.

I have a local repository with `master` and `dev` branches. Same thing on Github.

Another developer created a branch and pushed it to the Github, and then created a pull request. I merged this pull request into `master` on Github.

Locally, I did a `git pull` and my local `master` updated. However, now my `dev` branches on both local and Github don't have the change from that pull request.

I would like to make `dev` start all over from `master`. I basically spend 95% of my time in this `dev` branch and if I want to fire up a Rails console locally I want it to work as expected.

How do I do this (and what's it called)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that Git versioning only goes forward. Once you approve a PR to `master`, then `master` is at the latest point in the flow. If you want to incororpate these changes into `dev`, all you need to do is swap to the `dev` branch and then `merge` `master` into it:

```
git checkout dev
git merge master
```

Pulling the changes from `master` to `dev` is common practice after a release. However, in theory, there should never be any *changes* in `master` that don't exist in `dev`, as both `hotfix` branches and `release` branches should be merged into `dev` directly.

Feature branches in themselves should **only** go out to `dev`, with `dev` ultimately carrying those feature branch changes to `master` through means of a `release` branch.

**Urgent** changes can indeed be planned for `master`, though these should be created as a `hotfix` branch which gets merged into both `dev` *and* `master`.

This follows the process know as **[Git Flow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html)**, which has the following illustrated flow from top-to-bottom (and I would strongly recommend following):

[image: Git Flow]

Comment: This is fantastic. Git is so wide-open, and you can do whatever you want in it. It's overwhelming. Sometimes I just need someone to tell me what to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They are separate branches from Master, thus why they don't have the changes on Master.

Typically what you would do is now merge your master branch in with your dev branch.  There could be merge conflicts that you will have to resolve.

I am assuming that you want to keep your changes in dev but just add the stuff in master until you are ready to also push to master.

If you

```
git checkout dev
git merge master
```

Here is the basic branching and merging tutorial
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

And here is one from atlassian
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge